# How to remove texture from shaders?

Tags: shaders

It's my first time trying shaders. So I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm sorry if this is a stupide question. I've downloaded this model from the internet but it looks like textures are missing. At least one of this Nodes(?) is called face.png.001 and the face is colored. But I like the skin shader that came with the model. So is there a way to remove the texture from face and chest? If so how? (Please describe it for an idiot. I'm super new to this and have trouble understanding may technical terms used.)

[image]

EDIT:
My current settings
[image]
[image]
[image]
As you can see the regions marked as textured are of a darker color. The same happens if I render it with F12.
[image]
Removing the face texture node from the mix node has no effect. Can someone explain to me why that happens.

EDIT 2:
I found that there are several materials/shaders in this one object. I did not know that this was possible.
[image]
I could work around the problem by coping the nodes in the body material to the face material. But I would prefer to understand how it works and do it properly. I.e. how is the material assigned to only this faces? There are also Vertex Groups in this model but non of them match the violet area.

Comment: Do you have the texture? Did it come with the model download? If so, go to menu _File_ > _External Data_ > _Find Missing Files_. There you can navigate to the folder where the image texture is saved. Then click the button _Find Missing Files_.

Comment: No I don't have the textures

Comment: Well, then the texture node is useless and you can delete it and the mix node with which it is combined... unless you get the texture somewhere or any substitute for it.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann what do you mean with mix the node? unconnecting the node does nothing

Comment: With Edit 2 it seems to me that you should probably watch some beginners tutorials on materials, textures and the _Shader Editor_ if you had no idea that and how you can use multiple materials on an object and how to assign them to faces.

Answer (score 1):

Usually pink shows that there is a missing texture. However, in your screenshot it looks like the *Image Texture* node is plugged in the *Factor* input which wouldn't show up as pink even if the texture as missing. It took a while until I realized you are in *Solid* view:

[image: solid view]

In this view you don't see any textures or shaders. The only reason this would make it appear pink is that the material or the object is set to be shown as pink in the *Viewport Display* settings.

Go to the *Material Properties*, down to *Viewport Display* > *Color*. This might be pink - but this is not how the material will look like when you render the object, this is just for example to distinguish it from other materials in the viewport:

[image: material viewport display]

If there is no pink color set for *Viewport Display*, then it's possible that not the material is set to pink, but the object (although this is not likely since not the whole object is showing pink). This would mean in the *Viewport Shading* options the *Color* is set to *Object* instead of the default *Material*:

[image: viewport shading options]

In this case the pink color would be set in the *Object Properties* under *Viewport Display*:

[image: object viewport display]

Comment: I added more infos.